# How to export a sample of a file with AudioKit 5.0.b1?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, avaudiofile

I am trying to update my app so it can run using Xcode 12.0 beta 3 (12A8169g) and AudioKit 5.0.b1. Previously I had this code to export my `AKAudioFile` into a desired format and with defined start and end positions:

```
let sampleRate = audioFile.fileFormat.sampleRate
let fromSample = Int64(audioFile.duration * start * sampleRate)
let toSample = Int64(audioFile.duration * end * sampleRate)
audioFile.exportAsynchronously(name: "audio", baseDir: .temp, exportFormat: exportFormat, fromSample: fromSample, toSample: toSample) { file, error in
    guard let file = file else {
        return
    }
    success(file)
}
```

Currently it seems that I have to use [AKConverter](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/v5-develop/AudioKit/Audio%20Files/AKConverter.swift) for this task, but it seems that I cannot specify `fromSample` and `toSample` when I convert the file. So probably there is a way to first cut a portion of a file and then convert it to the desired format, but I did not find how can I efficiently do that. So how can I convert my code so that it works with v.5.0.b1?